# SSD on its way out?

Tags: ssd, smart

My SSD gives the impression that its dying (I've had to do numerous fsck after rebooting due to root becoming read-only).

I've done a smart scan but I'm not 100% sure how to interpret results:

https://pastebin.com/3CvV9LKZ

I don't get the impression the smart results point to the drive dying however?

With respect to log messages while the system is running:

https://pastebin.com/BwWaeAiW

The drive has been running 24/7 for two years and I'd like to return it, but I can't see a "smoking gun" from the SMART results.

Comment: This is in no way related to Ubuntu.

Comment: The SMART results do not point to anything serious. Generally when an SSD is dying you will see numbers in `198 Offline_Uncorrectable` and `199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count`. Your `199` count is zero. If you would like to do a more thorough test, consider running `sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sda` overnight. It will do a longer, more detailed test of the storage device.

Comment: Thanks @matigo. Appreciate the response. It's had me quite stumped. For now I've cloned it to another SSD with Clonezilla and will see if I'm getting similar logs with new SSD over the next few days. Separately I'll do an overnight smartctl long scan

Comment: Have you been using `fstrim` regularly, or mounted with option `discard` to ensure the disk can recover some clean space to work more optimally?